Use a string to choose an object in geometry nodes
I have object.001, object.002 … object.n and I'm using geometry nodes to draw lines from object.001 to empty.001, object.002 to empty.002, … object.n ➔ empty.n.
If I have a number field in my group input, I can turn it into the name of the object as shown, but is there a way of turning that string into a reference to object.001?

I know I can use a menu switch driven by a string, but I'm trying to save work here, not create it. Setting up all the members of the menu is more work than just choosing the target geometry in the geonodes modifier. Not pictured is that I can make the string say "empty.001" and I could plug that into my end point. And then maybe use the same input to say, set a material if I have material.001, material.002, etc..

Why not just put all of your connection objects into their own collection and then identify them with the collection object index instead?

I'm not sure what you're suggesting here, could you explain a bit more?
